# Is there a way to add the seconds to a time stamp if it is not present?

Tags: regex, sed, aix

I have a data file that runs through a map.  One of the fields reads a date/time stamp.  The map is setup to read MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS and this works most of the time.  Sometimes the time is not in the correct format and the :SS is not provided.

Correct data:
,1/11/2019 13:53:46,

Incorrect data:
,1/16/2019 11:27,

This is an old AIX 5.3 box.  I have tried some sed commands and some awk commands but have not had any sort of success.

```
 sed 's/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:00,/g'
```

I need to see
,1/16/2019 11:27:00,

but I am getting 
,1/16/2019 [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:00,

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/( [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}),/\1:00,/g'` or `sed 's/\( [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\),/\1:00,/g'`

Comment: Thank you,  sed 's/\( [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\),/\1:00,/g' worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sed 's/\( [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\),/\1:00,/g'
```

The pattern matches:

- `\( [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)` - Capturing group 1 (the value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - - space
  - `[0-9][0-9]`  - two digits
  - `:` - a colon
  - `[0-9][0-9]`  - two digits
- `,` - a comma

See this [POSIX BRE regex online demo](https://ideone.com/eS43rT).